# VueJS events between two separate components

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using VueJS inside Laravel 5.5. There are two components that I use in the same page. One of them creates the items, and the other one lists the items in order. So what I want to achieve is when an `Item` created successfully, `ItemList` component should update itself and get the latest items by making an AJAX request.

On ItemCreate Component `ItemCreate.vue`:

```
methods: {
        sendItemData: function () {
            this.$emit('items-updated');
            axios.post('/dashboard/item', {
                name: this.itemName,
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.status === 201) {
                        toastr.success('Crawler created successfully!', {timeout: 2000});
                        this.$emit('items-updated');
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    toastr.error(error, 'Ooops! Something went wrong!');
                })
        }
```

On ItemList Component `ItemList.vue`:

```
methods: {
        getItems: function () {
            axios.get('/items')
                .then(function (response) {
                    this.items = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    toastr.error(error, 'Ooops! Something went wrong!');
                })
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$on('items-updated', function () {
            this.getItems();
        })
    }
```

And lastly here is the main `app.js` setup:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('item-list', 
  require('./components/entities/item/ItemList'));
Vue.component('item-create', 
  require('./components/entities/item/ItemCreate'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [global EventBus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/):

in main.js:

```
window.EventBus = new Vue();
```

and then in your components:

```
EventBus.$emit('items-updated');

EventBus.$on('items-updated',() => {});
```